# Is it possible to add method invoked by clicking on a button in Android (not adding listener)

Tags: android, wpf, button, click

I wanted to invoke method when the button is clicked. I have found this solution

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do stuff here
    }
});
```

but this solution is horrible.

Is it possible to add method invocation in XML when the:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/actionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/actionButtonUnclicked" 
        />
```

is clicked? In similar manner that it can be done in Windows Phone's and WPF's `XAML`? Something like `android:onClick=clickMethod()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add method in xml using **android:onClick="clickMethod"** 
In xml:

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/actionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/actionButtonUnclicked" 
    android:onClick="clickMethod"
            />


and in activity/ fragment add
```

your method should receive View v

```
public void clickMethod(View v){
    // do smth
    }
```

PS: If you want to use same method for multiple buttons

> ```
>  public void clickMethod(View v){
>         // check for id
>        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
> //operation for button 1 click
> } else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2){ //operation for button 1 click
> }
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout elements -->
<Button android:id="@+id/actionButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Click me!"
  android:onClick="myButtonClick" />
<!-- even more layout elements -->
```

and in your class:

```
public void myButtonClick(View v) {
   // does something very interesting
}
```